# How to implement NTLM authentication in react-native app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, ntlm

Hey I am struggling with implementing NTLM authentication in a react native app. I am using this library https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm , but in order for it to work I first had to add a ton of node core modules from https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native and https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs for fs and even add js-md4 in httpntlm library itself to get md4 hashing for password to work.

Long story short, I think even after all that the connection gets closed after the first request, because my authentication fails due to invalid credentials.

I tested the same code and library with https in a node.js local server and it works, so it is not the credentials themselves that are not valid.

Any tips on how to implement this authentication in react-native?

This is the response from sendMessage1():

```
{
    "type": "default",
    "status": 401,
    "ok": false,
    "headers": {
        "map": {
            **"connection": "close",**
            "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
            "www-authenticate": "NTLM veryLongHash",
            "date": "Wed, 17 Jul 2019 14:15:34 GMT",
            "content-type": "text/html; charset=us-ascii",
            "content-length": "341"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://myAppUrl",
```

}

This is the code:

```
  const keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
  });

  const options = {
    url,
    username: 'Username',
    password: 'Password',
    workstation: '',
    domain: ''
  };


  const type1msg = ntlm.createType1Message(options);

  const sendType1Message = async () => {
    await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Accept: '*/*',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Authorization: type1msg
      },
      keepAlive: true,
      allowRedirects: false,
      agent: keepaliveAgent
    })
      .then(res => setImmediate(() => sendType3Message(res)))
      .catch(error => console.log('Error in send message1', error));
  };

  const sendType3Message = async res => {
    console.log('CONNECTION', res.headers.get('connection')); // Returns 'close'

    if (!res.headers.get('www-authenticate')) {
      console.log('Auth error: www-authenticate not found on response of second request');
    } else {
      const type2msg = ntlm.parseType2Message(res.headers.get('www-authenticate'));
      const type3msg = ntlm.createType3Message(type2msg, options);
      await RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', url, {
        Accept: '*/*',
        Connection: 'Close',
        Authorization: type3msg
      })
        .then(data => console.log('RESULT', data.data))
        .catch(e => console.log('Error', e));
    }
  };
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Kristine, I am running into the same issue, did you find any workaround to do NTLM auth in react native application.

Comment: Hey, no unfortunately I did not find a way to implement it directly in react native. My workaround was to implement a node server as a middleware and use that to make the API calls with NTLM authentication. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that issue before while i was trying to get data from Sharepoint Application in our servers.

I did not use any react native packages for overcome this issue. I wrote native modules (Java for Android & Objective-C for iOS) for requests and took the data back to JS side with callbacks.

You can find an example about how to write your own Native Modules here:

iOS: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

Android: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Maybe it is because you don't have privilege to add comment but this could have been a comment then as an answer, please see [How-to-write-a-good-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) . If you think you can explain the OP where the problem lies in code as described then it will be great ! Good Luck!

Comment: I am using react native expo and do not want to exit from the expo. Can you provide any workaround for doing NTLM auth in react native.